# Using user input to alert array elements within objects (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, user-input

I have a data hierarchy that contains several layers of objects and arrays. The structure looks like this:
[image: schema]

The data hierarchy is like this:

1. Cuesta - parent object
2. Clusters - objects within Cuesta
3. Divisions - objects within clusters
4. Departments - arrays within divisions (the department arrays contain two object elements, both with two properties each: course number, and course title).

Basically I need to prompt the user to specify a

1. Cluster (WED or MAS)
2. Division (BUS_ED for WED or MATH for MAS, etc.)
3. Department (CIS for BUS_ED or WELD for ENGR_TECH, etc.)

and then I need to write the entirety of information stored in the final array chosen (whose elements are individual objects).

Basically all I need to know is the syntax for using string variables to call objects.

I've been searching for a solution for an hour and a half now and I don't know what I'm missing. Any help would be deeply appreciated!

```
var clus = prompt("Enter cluster: ");  // User enters cluster
var div = prompt("Enter division: ");  // User enters division
var dep = prompt("Enter department: "); // User enters department

var Cuesta =
{
    WED: {
        BUS_ED: {
            CIS: [{
                course_number: " CIS 201",
                course_title: " Introduction to Computer Science"
            }, {
                course_number: " CIS 231",
                course_title: " Fundamentals of Computer Science"
            }],
            ECON: [{
                course_number: " ECON 101",
                course_title: " Introduction to Economics"
            }, {
                course_number: " ECON 1A",
                course_title: " Intermediary Economics"
            }]
        },
        ENGR_TECH: {
            ENGR: [{
                course_number: " ENGR 101",
                course_title: " Introduction to Engineering"
            }, {
                course_number: " ENGR 1A",
                course_title: " Intermediary Engineering"
            }],
            WELD: [{
                course_number: " WELD 101",
                course_title: " Introduction to Welding"
            }, {
                course_number: " WELD 1A",
                course_title: " Intermediary Welding"
            }]
        }
    },
    MAS: {

        PHY_SCI: {

            PHYS: [{
                course_number: " PHYS 101",
                course_title: " Introduction to Physics"
            }, {
                course_number: " PHYS 1A",
                course_title: " Intermediary Physics"
            }],

            CHEM: [{
                course_number: " CHEM 101",
                course_title: " Introduction to Chemistry"
            }, {
                course_number: " CHEM 1A",
                course_title: " Intermediary Chemistry"
            }]
        },

        MATH: {
            MATH: [{
                course_number: " MATH 101",
                course_title: " Introduction to Mathematics"
            }, {
                course_number: " MATH 1A",
                course_title: " Intermediate Mathematics"
            }]
        },

        BIO: {
            BIO: [{
                course_number: " BIO 101",
                course_title: " Introduction to Biology"
            }, {
                course_number: " BIO 1A",
                course_title: " Intermediate Biology"
            }]
        }
    }
}

var out = Cuesta. + clus. + div. + dep;
/* My attempt at taking the user input to specify a department (array) whose contents I write to the
 webpage*/

document.write("Course number:" + out.[0].course_number + "Course title:");
/*My attempt at writing the user-selected department array to the webpage*/
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: I just posted the code, sorry this is my first time posting on SO, I'm about as newb as it gets. For some reason, some of the code is in a scroll window and the rest is above it, but it's all one program. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use nested objects so have one overall object at which point you could access its properties in this format `exampleObject['property']` that could access your sub objects and their properties could be accessed like this `exampleObject['subObject']['property']`
That set up should allow you to use string inputs or variables to access different properties. 
Setup for the object itself would look like this

```
var exampleObject={
    subObject:{
        property:'value',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the mistake I made. I hadn't learned the difference between dot notation and bracket notation for specifying elements in objects. Only bracket notation can be used to use a variable string value to specify a property within an object. Dot notation is only good for hardcoding the call to the object property. Thank you very much for your help! I'm brand new to this site, but let me know how I can return the favor in the form of votes/likes/etc.

Comment: marking it as the answer add reputation points. voting for it adds reputation but you don't have enough reputation to vote quite yet. thanks. glad to help